# Im working on "Matchismo" the app for the stanford itunes university courses, and on the first assignment I get an issue on my PlayingCrad.m file.

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import "PlayingCard.h"


@implementation PlayingCard

-(NSString *)contents
{
NSArray *rankStrings = [PlayingCard rankStrings];
return [rankStrings[self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
```

**/Users/Pichard93/Desktop/Matchismo2/Matchismo2/PlayingCard.m:18:33: Property 'rank' not             found on object of type 'PlayingCard'**
//This is the issue i get ^^

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `rank` should be declared as a property and is not. Declare it the interface file or as a class extension in the implementation file.

Basically the error messages do mostly make sense, try to figure out what them mean pertaining to your code. In this case the error message rather explicitly stated that `rank` is not found for the class `PlayingCard` which means not declared.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your PlayingCard.h

@property (nonatomic)NSUInteger rank;